# Is there a way to set a build config field for Espresso tests (or something similar)?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, buildconfig

I'm working on automated testing in Android, and I'm trying to figure out a way to determine - in code - if it's being executed via Espresso or not. I've come across the following:

```
ActivityManager.isRunningInTestHarness()
```

but that doesn't work. Is there something similar I can do? Is there a way to add a buildConfigField for an Espresso test in build.gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to reliably find out whether your app is running instrumented by your test suite is to try to load a test suite class:

```
private boolean isInstrumentedRun() {
    boolean result;
    try {
        getApplication().getClassLoader().loadClass(
                "my.fully.qualified.TestProjectClass");
        result = true;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```